# Listview showing wrong image at first row

Tags: java, android

I have already searched through SO, and found 4 similar questions but it seem this problem is different kind. I also spent about about 7 hours to solve this single bug, and didn't found where I did wrong.

**THE PROBLEM:**
Every row in ListView contain two images. When I launch the activity, either one or both of imageView in first row displaying wrong image and this only happen at **sometimes** after launch. Where, sometimes, the row displaying correct images after launch.

When I scroll down hiding the first row, and then scroll up again, the images change to correct images.

**TRIED SOLUTION:**
I found only one solution, is to set convertView = null at the beginning of getView method. Yes, it's works, imageView display correctly, but leading to other problem and bug. Scrolling become not smooth and sometimes some images became too small from what it should be.

**NOTE:**
There is no problem with data, data fetching correctly for every rows, after i run debug.

**MY CODE**
MatchAdapter.class
getView method

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Match entry = listMatch.get(position);

    MatchAdapter.ViewHolder myViewHolder;

    if(convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.match_row, parent, false);

        myViewHolder = new MatchAdapter.ViewHolder();

        myViewHolder.home_team_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.home_team_name);
        myViewHolder.away_team_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.away_team_name);
        myViewHolder.home_logo_view = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.home_team_logo);
        myViewHolder.away_logo_view = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.away_team_logo);
        myViewHolder.venue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.venue);
        myViewHolder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        convertView.setTag(myViewHolder); 

    } else {
        myViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
    }

    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.context, "com.myapps", R.drawable.team_logo);

    imageLoader.DisplayImage("http://myapps.com/assets/images/logos/"+ entry.getHome_team_logo(), 
            myViewHolder.home_logo_view);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage("http://myapps.com/assets/images/logos/" + entry.getAway_team_logo(), 
            myViewHolder.away_logo_view); 

    myViewHolder.home_team_name.setText(entry.getHome_team_name());
    myViewHolder.away_team_name.setText(entry.getAway_team_name());
    myViewHolder.venue.setText(entry.getVenue());
    myViewHolder.time.setText(entry.getTime());

    return convertView;
}
```

Other related code:

[ImageLoader.class](http://www.androidsnippets.com/imagesloaderclass) (I don't want this question become too long to scroll)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I redesign my whole code using lazylist, following example by fedor [Simple demo of a LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

I found it from here [How do I do a lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

---

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the following code is

> Match entry = listMatch.get(position);

too early. ListView's getView is multithreaded and It take some time in inflate the layout to convert view. And somehow the variable reference became incorrect.

Call     Match entry = listMatch.get(position); after

else {
        myViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
    }

Comment: When you found The images are not correct, Are the text correct?

Comment: Yes, text display correctly. You can get my apps at google play to test. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jadualbola.lite

Comment: If the text are inflating correctly and only images aren't I think it is because ImageLoader class. I have been in similar case before, you can solve it in two way. 1. Change your imageloader with AndroidQuery Library. 2. try call like imageLoader.DisplayImage("http://myapps.com/assets/images/logos/"+ listMatch.get(position).getHome_team_logo(), 
            myViewHolder.home_logo_view);